# Kubernetes in AWS with traefic reachable only from the pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, traefik, amazon-eks

I have an AWS EKS deployment where I can reach the pod and see my Node app running as under

```sh
kubectl exec -it my-app-898f57d6f-dsfg6 /bin/bash

root@my-app-898f57d6f-dsfg6:/usr/src/app# curl localhost

**Hello World!!**
```

I used Traefik and here is what I see in:

http://a262f21c7a0c740949c3321ab77a0259-639235071.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8080

or

http://hostname-v1.local:8080/dashboard/

[image: image1]

However, when I try to access my pod from the internet using

`http://hostname-v1.local`

I got Service Unavailable as so:

[image: image2]

So my question is why I can not reach my server from the internet even if it's correctly working?

Note that hostname-v1.local is just an /etc/hosts mapping to the IP of the traefik LoadBalancer as so

```sh
traefik-ingress-service   LoadBalancer   10.100.113.186   a262f21c7a0c740949c3321ab77a0259-639235071.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

So

```sh
host a262f21c7a0c740949c3321ab77a0259-639235071.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

returns

```sh
a262f21c7a0c740949c3321ab77a0259-639235071.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 34.195.130.205
a262f21c7a0c740949c3321ab77a0259-639235071.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 107.22.153.204
a262f21c7a0c740949c3321ab77a0259-639235071.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 52.44.97.64
```

An what I did is just in /etc/hosts

```sh
cat /etc/hosts

34.195.130.205 hostname-v1.local
```

I just want to be able to do

`http://hostname-v1.local`

or

`curl hostname-v1.local`

And get back:

`**Hello World!!**`

Like in the pod

Could someone help identify what is the issue?

BR

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/

Comment: @MasterOfTheHouse Does the above solve your issue?